# Simulate the Perelian atmosphere circulation model

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate the Perelian atmosphere circulation model.
I tried NASA's AtmosModeler Simulator, but it was not what I was thinking. I designed the experiment, but I could not get the right result because of the heat capacity of the air.
Are there any appropriate libraries or programs?